# xcode - console output also in a file?

Tags: xcode, console, location, tail

i'd like to tail -f the output console of XCode,
and have it present in the xcode UI itself.
is the console mirrored in a file somewhere ?

i greped -r through ~/Library/Developer/Xcode but didn't find any matches.